# Lisent to bluetooth activity in pebble-js-sdk

Tags: pebble-watch, pebble-sdk, cloudpebble

I know to listen on bluetooth connection/disconnection activities using the Pebble C SDK.
How to achieve the same using the javascript SDK ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no equivalent event service in the PebbleKitJS API. It is simply not possible.

Comment: So how should I go about implementing the event service ?
I have an app which was written purely using PebbleKitJS.

Comment: Are you using [Pebble.js](https://github.com/pebble/pebblejs)? That's the only way to write a Pebble app in Javascript.

If so, there unfortunately isn't any way to listen for this event.

Comment: Yes am using Pebble.js

Comment: If you are using Pebble.js you will not be able to change anything on the screen once you lost the connection. Getting that event would not really help you.

Comment: Is there any good guide on integrating a pebble C app with pebble.js script ?

Answer (score 0):

The PebbleKitJS API cannot be used to build a Pebble app, it is only a method of transferring data such as GPS location and internet information.

You would not need to know if the Pebble was connected as the program would only run when called upon by an application installed on Pebble.

Comment: He added more comments to say that he is using Pebble.js: https://github.com/pebble/pebblejs